# Is it ok to apply to a paid position and also offer volunteer work for different work at the same company?

Tags: professionalism, unprofessional-behavior, volunteering

I am thinking of offering to do some volunteer based work for a Company X.  I know Company X would appreciate this kind of work because they do not yet have anyone qualified enough to do it and it is something that would be very profitable for them.  However, at the same time, they do not yet have funding for this position.  My reasoning behind doing this is because: (1) I need experience, (2) it would not take up a significant amount of my time, (3) the location is convenient for me, and (4) it's absolutely what I want to be doing (as a career).

Company X also has openings for two other positions which are sort of related but are paid, both of which I believe I am qualified for.

Would Company X find it strange for me to apply to paid positions but also be offering some volunteer work at the same time?  What would be the most professional way to go about this (e.g. do I mention in my cover letter for the paid positions my volunteer offering, or do I pretend that they are all separate jobs at separate companies)?

Comment: Where are you and what is the "volunteer" work you are proposing? In many jurisdictions it is illegal for a company to accept work done free (violation of minimum-wage law).

Comment: More specifically, it's often illegal for a company to accept volunteer work *from employees*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to do JOB_B for free why should the company pay you to do JOB_A? Typically once you 'volunteer' for a position then you should kiss the chances of getting a paid position(or even moving from volunteered to a paid position) goodbye.

Since you're talking about profitability I'm making the assumption that this company is a for-profit corporation or company. In which case 'volunteer' work is inappropriate. There are a couple reasons for this...

Have you ever hosted an event or done a give away for a free item/entry? There's a perception about free things, even free volunteer things. Let's take fixing a computer as an example. If you fix a computer for free often a couple of things will happen:

- They will expect you to perform additional fixes to the computer in
  the future for free.
- They will blame you for any future problems with the computer or
  related technology no matter what the real cause.
- They will begin expecting other repairs for free(I once got a call
  about a microwave!)
- They often don't appreciate the time/effort put into the repair

Extrapolate this to a job. I've seen 'volunteers' and I've seen how their work is treated/valued after the fact. In some, rare, places their contributions are valued and, occasionally, they even move up into a paid position. But, typically, anything they've done is dismissed after the fact as done by someone who 'didn't know what they were doing'. And, let's be honest, you want to use this as a learning experience and you've not done it before - do you have the skills to make a product from scratch in this area? If the answer is yes then you have the skills to be paid for that.

Finally, taking this job as 'unpaid', in the end, devalues this work for everyone in the field. If a company can get good enough, or at least profitable, work without paying anyone why would they pay a decent wage?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't publicise any intent to offer your time for more volunteer work before getting the paid job. Of course, if it comes up in subsequent conversation with relevant people (manager at high enough level to formally sanction your division of labour, and people involved with that project / area of work who can 'make things happen' to get you on the project), you can consider mentioning that you're also interested it. I would investigate whether there's anyone you could shadow who's already working in that area.

If you absolutely want to do this, and you get the paid job, the trick will be to make sure you're formally allowed to spend some of your agreed working hours working on 'volunteer' work without compromising your primary role.

Absolutely key is to get your employment contract worded so that it either doesn't formally include these duties, or gives you a percentage of time to spend on other projects. HR won't prompt for this unless they're *very* conscientious and if you don't pursue this line of negotiation you'll realise they've managed to get two employees for the price of one, you'll have too much work and you'll just burn out.